# How to configure NLog programmatically for Async target?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to configure Nlog programmatically for use with async method. However it seems that the documentation mostly provides examples for configuration using [XML](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target). A minimal example using code for an older NLog version is provided [here](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_Wrappers_AsyncTargetWrapper.htm).

I would like to do that by using `NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration()`, so here is how I proceeded:

```
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

// Targets:
NLog.Targets.FileTarget fileTarget = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("fileTarget")
            {
                FileName = "\\MyLogFileDirectory.txt",
                ArchiveAboveSize = 25000000,
                MaxArchiveFiles = 10
            };

//Handle Async:
NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper asyncFileTarget = new NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget)
            {
                Name = fileTarget.Name,
                QueueLimit = 10,
                OverflowAction = NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Discard
            };
config.AddTarget(asyncFileTarget);

// Rules: 
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, fileTarget, "MyLog");

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

EDITS:

My question is the following:
Does a separate Rule needs to be created for `asyncFileTarget` or is it enough to add the rule for fileTarget ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important that the `AddRule` references the AsyncWrapper, else it will write directly to the target without buffering.

```
// Apply Async
NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper asyncFileTarget = new NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget)
{
   Name = fileTarget.Name,
   QueueLimit = 10,
   OverflowAction = NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Discard
};

// WriteTo Async
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, asyncFileTarget, "MyLog");
```

Notice that `AddRule` internally automatically calls `AddTarget`