# What is a fast async text writer that can be used to log a line of text to a csv file?

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, logging, file-writing

I am trying to find a text writer that will not block it's calling thread. It will be called over 400k times a day and will be used for logging lines of text to a csv file. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public void callWriter()
        {

            textwriter.WriteToFileAsync(LINE_OF_DATA);

            //continue with rest of my program while file gets written to
        }

public async void WriteToFileAsync(string data)
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter =
                new StreamWriter
                (
                    _path,
                    APPEND_FILE,
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    BUFFER_SIZE_IN_BYTES
                ))
            {
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(data);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `async void` is definitely *not* the best option.

Comment: ~4.62 calls per second is low volume.

Comment: Yes but it's going to have to find the end of a 400k line file which takes a long time.

Comment: Find? How are you doing that? `fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)` is extremely fast. Separate your stream from your reader.

Comment: @AlexanderLiteplo maybe "writing to a file" is not the bet solution to a problem - could a _database_ be an option? they're _made_ for handling lots and lots of data entries.

Comment: I meant the file writer will have to find the last line of the file each call.

Comment: Just as a side question - is this writing to a file basically just for normal application trace logging, or for something else? If it's for logging, you'll be hard-pressed to beat NLog's performance.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann It has to be written to a text file unfortunately.

Comment: @majixin yes its for logging

Comment: First, StreamWriter will not look for the last line in the file, it will simply start writing where the file currently ends. It should be not much slower than starting to write at the start. Secondly, if you call this twice there is no guarantee the second call will succeed if the first call is still not yet done, because the first call will hold the file open and then the second call will fail.

Comment: And 400k calls a day is not a problem, I daresay the issue I mentioned in my other comment regarding two calls would probably not be a problem either **provided** that the calls are spaced out. However, if you have 400k calls a day, but with a high volume of them at the start of the day, then those failures might start to crop up.

Comment: If you want to have a log that doesn't block the calling code then add a queue, and have a dedicated thread that reads from the queue and writes to the log file. Then your log method only needs to put the log entry into the queue and not actually deal with the file. Or better yet, use one of the many 3rd party logging libraries that solves this for you so you don't have to.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Log4Net.Async/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on clarifying your need is for logging in the comments, I would suggest using NLog.

Here's a SO post on configuring NLog, for which the question is important, since any buffer for logging is (as others have stated) a queue, which needs to be sized accordingly, otherwise it 'overflows' and messages can be lost.

It is better not to rely on rolling your own solution here. Projects that have been through several public iterations of bug-fixes and dealing with all sorts of scenarios will be more robust and be better performing.

[How to configure NLog programmatically for Async target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719141/how-to-configure-nlog-programmatically-for-async-target)

You can find performance comparisons of NLog to other .NET logging frameworks/libraries and see that NLog is fastest.